Is there a way to slowly scroll down on a scrollable element inside a webpage and then stop once a button is found via Python Selenium
My problem is there is a scrollable panel or area inside this webpage and I can't make the scrolling stop once the element I'm trying to locate is found. It always instantly scrolls to a certain area.
This is my current code sample:
XPATH_1 = 'xpath_of_scrollable_panel_inside_webpage'
XPATH_2= context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPATH_1)
context.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", XPATH_




This script just instantly scrolls at the bottom of the scrollable panel inside a webpage, I can't make it stop once the element I'm trying to locate is found

What is your end goal, what are you trying to achieve?

you should work more on your code, something like a variable True/False init False and while is False scroll

@BarrythePlatipus I want to slowly scroll until the element I'm looking for is located by the webdriver, the element is around at the middle of the scrollable panel, but the code I got just instantly scrolls down to the bottom of the page.
